# Why does WaitForMultipleObjects() stop working after one loop?

Tags: c++, loops, winapi, directsound, waitformultipleobjects

I am using DirectSound to play music in C++. I am using DSBPOSITIONNOTIFICATION variables to determine when playback of the `secondaryBuffer` variable (of type `IDirectSoundBuffer8*`) has reached either one quarter, three quarters or the end of its size. The code used to create the notifications and play the music is shown below.

```
LPDIRECTSOUNDNOTIFY8 directSoundNotify;
HANDLE playEventHandles[3];
playEventHandles[0] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
playEventHandles[1] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
playEventHandles[2] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

secondaryBuffer->QueryInterface(IID_IDirectSoundNotify8, (LPVOID*)&directSoundNotify);

//This is the size of secondaryBuffer
int averageBytes = wfx.Format.nAvgBytesPerSec * 4;

//Create notification information
DSBPOSITIONNOTIFY positionNotify[3];
positionNotify[0].dwOffset = averageBytes / 4;
positionNotify[0].hEventNotify = playEventHandles[0];
positionNotify[1].dwOffset = averageBytes - (averageBytes / 4);
positionNotify[1].hEventNotify = playEventHandles[1];
positionNotify[2].dwOffset = averageBytes;
positionNotify[2].hEventNotify = playEventHandles[2];
directSoundNotify->SetNotificationPositions(1, positionNotify);
directSoundNotify->Release();

secondaryBuffer->Play(0, 0, 0);

do
{
    //Wait for notifications
    DWORD notification = WaitForMultipleObjects(3, playEventHandles, FALSE, INFINITE);

    //First quarter notification - Fill second half if not all data has been received
    if (notification == 0)
    {
        //This function is handled elsewhere in the program - It obtains music from a server using sockets
        ReceiveMusic();
    }
    //Third quarter notification - Fill first half if not all data has been received
    else if (notification == 1)
    {
        ReceiveMusic();
    }
    //Playback ended notification - Reset play position
    else if (notification == 2)
    {
        secondaryBuffer->SetCurrentPosition(0);
        secondaryBuffer->Play(0, 0, 0);
    }
} while (size < dataBufferSize); //While size (current amount of song loaded) is less than dataBufferSize (total size of song that is in the process of being loaded)
//The size and dataBufferSize are initialised and handled elsewhere in the program, but they work properly - There shouldn't be a problem with the loop termination condition
```

The function `WaitForMultipleObjects()` is able to detect when an event has occurred (it successfully notices the first quarter event). However, it stops working on the second loop. The program reaches the function, but it just sits there forever without noticing when another event has occurred (I'm pretty sure the `secondaryBuffer` is still playing, so it should notice that it has reached three quarters playback or has stopped). How can I change the code so that the function actually notices the events on future loops?

Comment: Your first argument to SetNotificationPositions() is clearly wrong, it needs to be 3.

Comment: @HansPassant I used 3 as the first parameter, but now the function pauses on the first loop. Playback reaches the first quarter (where the first notification should occur), but the `WaitForMultipleObjects()` function does not return a value.

Comment: @HansPassant is right, you definitely need to pass 3 into SetNotificationPositions(). The pause you get is a different problem... For starters, make sure you created the secondary buffer with the DSBCAPS_CTRLPOSITIONNOTIFY flag. Also, check the return value from Play() to make sure you're getting back `DS_OK`.

Comment: `WaitForMultipleObjects` and automatic reset events are a bug waiting to happen. Use manual reset events if you plan to use them with `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

Comment: @MarkWaterman `secondaryBuffer` is initialised as `nullptr`. I tried using the suggested flag in the line of code where I lock the buffer in order to write music to it (`secondaryBuffer->Lock(dwOffset, averageBytes / 2, (void**)&bufferPtr1, (DWORD*)&bufferSize1, (void**)&bufferPtr2, (DWORD*)&bufferSize2, DSBCAPS_CTRLPOSITIONNOTIFY);
`), but the program considered the flag to be an invalid argument.

Comment: @IInspectable Manual reset events? How do I add those and where?

Comment: In the code that you wrote, you create three automatic reset events. Why did you choose auto reset?

Comment: @IInspectable I've changed the second parameter of each `CreateEvent()` function to `TRUE` so that they are set to manual. Additionally, I've found that the value of `Play()` is `S_OK`, but the problem still persists and the `WaitForMultipleObjects` function gets stuck waiting forever on the second loop.

Comment: @IInspectable Error in previous comment: It gets stuck on the first loop.

Comment: When you're creating your secondary buffer, you should be setting the DSBCAPS_CTRLPOSITIONNOTIFY flag in the [DSBUFFERDESC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.dsbufferdesc(v=vs.85).aspx) structure (dwFlags field) that you pass into IDirectSound8::CreateSoundBuffer(). You don't use that flag when locking the buffer.

Comment: ... and check the return value of SetNotificationPositions() for `DS_OK` while you're at it!!

Comment: @MarkWaterman I'm using `bufferDesc.dwFlags = DSBCAPS_CTRLVOLUME | DSBCAPS_GLOBALFOCUS | DSBCAPS_CTRLPOSITIONNOTIFY;` when creating the `DSBUFFERDESC` structure, but the problem still persists.

Comment: @MarkWaterman Checking the result of `SetNotificationPositions()` has yielded some new info. It returns a value of `E_INVALIDARG` when it's set to `SetNotificationPositions(3, positionNotify);`.

Comment: Ooh, that's progress! ... `positionNotify[2].dwOffset`sure looks suspicious upon closer inspection. I think using the length as the offset puts you past the end of the buffer there.

Comment: @MarkWaterman Sure enough, changing the value of `positionNotify[2].dwOffset` to `DSBPN_OFFSETSTOP` fixed the problem. :)